# Inspect iOS user's documents folder remotely

Tags: ios, documents, data-recovery

Recently a user of one of my apps reported that all her data was lost when she updated the app. I think this is a long shot, but is there anyway for me to inspect her 'documents' folder within the app on her iPad? Or a way for her to send me her document folder so I can see what's going on and hopefully salvage the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If she is a fairly technically capable user, you could have her use PhoneDisk http://www.macroplant.com/phonedisk/ to mount your app's sandbox and inspect the Documents folder.

Answer (score -1):

If it is a jailbroken device you could ask her to download teamviewer, then ssh into the iPad.
Never tried it though! But that was an idea I got when I saw your question.

http://www.idownloadblog.com/2011/03/14/how-to-ssh-into-your-iphone/